# Degraded performance of a overridden getter in node/v8

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I ran into this strange scenario where overriding a property getter is severely impacting performance (which will only be noticeable with lot of computation like sorting in the example below).

In the following example code, I have 3 `classes`, `VP`, `F1` and `F2`. `F1` has a property called `#vp` with a corresponding getter that returns this private member. `F2` extends `F1` and overrides the `vp` getter which simply delegates to `super.vp`. I actually don't need to do this but because I have to override the setter I also need to implement the getter as per JavaScript spec.

In the following code, I sort a million random numbers and the difference in performance using `F1` object vs `F2` object is around 1 second `vs` 5 seconds.

```
import { performance } from 'perf_hooks';

class VP {
    #idx = 0;
    getValue(row) { return row[this.#idx]; }
}

class F1 {
    #vp;
    set vp(vp) { this.#vp = vp; }
    get vp() { return this.#vp; }
}

class F2 extends F1 {
    #o;
    set vp(vp) { super.vp = vp; this.#o = 1; }
    get vp() { return super.vp; }
}

const vp = new VP();
const f1 = new F1();
f1.vp = vp;
const f2 = new F2();
f2.vp = vp;

function getData(size) {
        const data = new Array();
        for(let i=0;i<size;i++) data[i] = [Math.random()*1000000];
        return data;
}

const data = getData(1000000);
const t1 = performance.now();
// data.sort((a,b) => f1.vp.getValue(a) - f1.vp.getValue(b)); // 940ms
// data.sort((a,b) => { let vp = f1.vp; return vp.getValue(a) - vp.getValue(b); }); // 945ms
data.sort((a,b) => f2.vp.getValue(a) - f2.vp.getValue(b)); // 4990ms
// data.sort((a,b) => { let vp = f2.vp; return vp.getValue(a) - vp.getValue(b); }); // 3146ms
const t2 = performance.now();
console.debug(t2-t1);
```

At the moment I got away by getting rid of the setter/getter in F2 and instead using a separate setVP API to set the value. But I am curious as to why overriding the getter is making it so slow.

Comment: It's hard to know in this case, but sometimes small changes in code can cause V8 drop certain optimizations and drastically change the performance.  For example, when an object structure is known in advance to the V8 compiler, it can lay out essentially a C struct that holds that class data, but as soon as you dynamically assign something different, it can void that optimized access structure.

Comment: I'd say it's the increased complexity times the huge number of calls involved. To execute `getValue` it has to find `f2.vp` (nothing), `F2.prototype.vp` (found getter), call getter, resolve `super` (class F1), find `super.vp` (found), call second getter, get `this.#vp` (instance of VP), get `vp.getValue` (nothing), `VP.prototype.getValue` (found method), call it, resolve `this.#idx`, resolve schema for `row` and find property `row[0]`. Take a look at the [linked part of this talk about "Locating the value of an objects property in memory"](https://youtu.be/_VHNTC67NR8?t=318)

Comment: test this: `const tmp = f2.vp; data.sort((a,b) => tmp.getValue(a) - tmp.getValue(b));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

You didn't say which version of V8 you're using, so I have to guess a bit, which in this particular case is not too hard...

The reason for the slowdown you're seeing is not the fact that you're overriding the getter; it's the fact that you're using `super.vp` in the overriding getter.

With Node 15.11 (V8 8.6) I can reproduce your results; with current V8 (9.0/9.1) I cannot. One difference between those versions is the work described here: https://v8.dev/blog/fast-super, which very much fits this scenario.

So if you simply update (to Chrome 90+, or current Node nightly builds which I guess will become Node 16) when updates are available, your code will magically speed up.

---

If you need a workaround that works *today*, find a way to avoid using `super` on the hot path. For example by using a different name in the subclass, and getting to the inherited getter via regular property lookup, like so:

```js
class F2 extends F1 {
  #o;
  set vp2(vp) { this.vp = vp; this.#o = 1; }
  get vp2() { return this.vp; }
}
```

which I guess is similar to the "setVP API" you hinted at. Or you could stop using private fields and just access `_vp` (instead of `#vp`) directly from `F2`, skipping the super accessor:

```js
class F1 {
  _vp;
  set vp(vp) { this._vp = vp; }
  get vp() { return this._vp; }
}

class F2 extends F1 {
  #o;
  set vp(vp) { this._vp = vp; this.#o = 1; }
  get vp() { return this._vp; }
}
```